Mouse-Window-Interface Bug in Windows 11 (possibly after update)
I have a bizarre bug. Right after the Windows login, everything works fine, but after approximately 3-10 minutes, the mouse/window/taskbar interaction does not work anymore. I can move the mouse and still use it normally on the window that was active when the bug occurred but clicking on any other window or the taskbar does not work anymore.
Some other things I observed:

Full logout or restart is not necessary just locking windows and logging back in fixes the issue for a short while

After uninstalling a recent update, it starts to work again for a short while, then it reverts to the bug again

DISM scan repaired the issue for a little while (works only once for each restart)

When I close the only window that I still can interact with, none of the windows can be interacted with anymore. For one other window the mouse over effects (e.g. the x for closing the window) start to work but clicking does not work.

Interacting with the windows by using the keyboard works without problems.

When I change the window's focus via Alt-Tab and click into the window the focus changes "away" from that window (e.g. apparently to a different GUI element, not always sure which one).


Any ideas about the cause of this problem or troubleshooting ideas?
Other things I tried:

SFC check/repair: no (permanent) effect
DISM check/repair no (permanent) effect


When I experienced this issue a number years ago, it turned out, the drive was failing. It was less the mouse stopped working, more I/O errors were queued up, and it took a while for my inputs to be processed.

@Ramhound Thanks, wmic diskdrive get model,status gives a green light. How did you very that the drive was failing?

The drive simply failed.  If your drive is failing, and it is generating I/O errors, Windows will eventually complain and generate a warning notification. In my case the actions eventually happened, it's not clear, if that is the case for you. In my case I also would have to wait for things like the secure desktop to appear after hitting the keyboard shortcut for it.  After a few minutes actions would "catch up".
